# SQL: Find entries that don't exist

Tags: sql-server

I know this sounds backwards but I am looking for a way to search groups of records where a group does not contain a particular field.

We receive email data from multiple companies, parse the data into our database and then retrieve the data for our use.  For example, an email might come through with Name, Address, City, State, Zip and Phone.  Each of these properties are stored in a different row with the rows being associated by a common email_id (I know how inefficient this is, I inherited this and am changing it in the near future).

Here is an example of some rows:

```
ID         EmailID          Field_Name             Field_Value
1234       4556             Name                   Joe Bob
1235       4556             Address                123 Main St.
1236       4556             City                   New York
1237       4556             State                  New York
1238       4556             Zip                    01234
1239       4556             Phone                  1112223333
1240       4557             Name                   Joe Bob
1241       4557             Address                123 Main St.
1242       4557             City                   New York
1243       4557             State                  New York
1244       4557             Zip                    01234
(no phone field for email_id 4557 on purpose)
```

When I retrieve this data I specify the fields in the SELECT statement (SELECT Name, Address, ...) and have recently started to get an error of "Phone field not found" which I believe means that one of these groups of emails did not have a 'Phone' field entered.

My dilemma is how to search for something that is missing.  I would like to be able to run a query that would return the emailID of any email that does not have an associated 'Phone' field.  Using the data from above the query would return emailID 4557 since it has no Phone field.

I am on MSSQL Server 8 if that matters.

TIA,
Brian

Comment: FYI, you would be on Microsoft SQL Server 2008, there is no version 8 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use either a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or a `NOT EXISTS` to get the offending records.

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable yt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  EmailID     
          FROM    YourTable
          WHERE   Field_Name = 'Phone'
        ) yte ON yte.EmailID = yt.EmailID
WHERE   yte.EmailID IS NULL
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable yt
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT  EmailID     
          FROM    YourTable
          WHERE   Field_Name = 'Phone'
                  AND yt.EmailID = EmailID
        )
```

A good read about the difference (similarity) about both methods can be found [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)

Comment: [Two refreshes later] You really should test and finalize your scripts before you post them. Answers should be about accuracy, not speed.

Comment: @Philip, true but it was only after I've posted a correct LEFT JOIN answer I wanted to add an alternative using NOT EXISTS. The NOT EXISTS solution however did contain an error at first (as you've noticed). For the record, I did not intentionally post a wrong solution just to change it later on with a correct one.

Answer (score 5):

@Lieven is correct, and a slightly more intuitive way to get the `NOT EXISTS` result is to use `NOT IN` (the execution plans should be the same):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable
WHERE  emailid NOT IN(
          SELECT  EmailID     
          FROM    YourTable
          WHERE   Field_Name = 'Phone')
```

**EDIT:**

As Lieven points out in the comments, this can have unexpected results if you have `NULL` values in the field to be checked againast, in this instance `emailID`.

Comment: +1 because I'm pretty sure this would work in this instance but beware it can fail (return unexpected results) when there are NULL values present.

Comment: @Lieven - good point, I forgot to include that.  I'll add a note.